# ObjectBox browser is not available

Tags: android, objectbox

We are migrating from ObjectBox 0.9.15 to 1.3.4.

After updating classes (removing @Relation, etc) we added dependency for ObjectBox Browser but it does not start. I tried to debug what happens under the hood but it is simple:

```
public boolean start(Context context) {
    if(!BoxStore.isObjectBrowserAvailable()) {
      return false;
    } 
    // main logic below
}
```

`BoxStore.isObjectBrowserAvailable()` returns false. Unfortunately, it is a native method `public static native boolean isObjectBrowserAvailable()`
so I don't know what can I do next.

I triple-checked `build.gradle` and it looks well:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven { url "http://objectbox.net/beta-repo/" }
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'io.objectbox:objectbox-gradle-plugin:1.3.4'
    }
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
dependencies {
    debugCompile "io.objectbox:objectbox-android-objectbrowser:1.3.4"
    releaseCompile "io.objectbox:objectbox-android:1.3.4"
}
apply plugin: 'io.objectbox'
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like it is a temporary issue. I downgraded version to '1.2.2.' and '1.1.0' and browser starts there.

Opened an [issue on Github](https://github.com/objectbox/objectbox-java/issues/324)

Answer (score 0):

The version 2.2.0 of objectbox solved the issue.